# JAAS - How can the Subject be retrieved outside of the LoginModule?

Tags: java, tomcat8, jaas

I'm using Tomcat 8 and need to obtain the Subject outside of the LoginModule.
I've already tried:

```
Subject subject = Subject.getSubject(AccessController.getContext());
```

But that just returns null every time.
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is the Java SE way. In Java EE, the only standardized way to acquire the JAAS `Subject` is via the JACC `PolicyContext`, which Tomcat does not for the time being support (nor is required to). Recommended reading: http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2014/02/jaas-in-java-ee-is-not-universal.html

Answer (score 0):

I use a custom `Principal` that can contain a `Subject`, and have the JAAS login module set that as the `Principal`, then I use `request.getUserPrincipal()` to get it back inside the web-app, cast it to my custom class, and call `getSubject()`.

Comment: I was hoping there was some standard JAAS way to retrieve the Subject.  But I've looked and looked, and not found anything.  I guess creating some kind of hack, such as yours, is the only way.  Seems like JAAS is severely lacking in some areas, such as retrieving a Subject, and particularly, handling javax.security.auth.login.LoginExceptions
 thrown from the login() method.  JAAS just swallows the exception and redirects you to the error page specified in your web.xml.  You have no access to the LoginException.  Anyway, thank you for answer.  I'll try it out.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah. It appears to have been designed for J2EE and then parts of it back-ported to the Servlet specification. It seems to work back to front every time I look at it. I also had to add the error and warning essage a as public credentials of the Subject so I could get at the in the error page.